# How to chart a per minute figure from an incrementing number in Munin

Tags: munin, rrdtool

I've got a database number that increments in real time with certain page views.

I want to make a Munin chart which charts not the total, but how it's changed from minute to minute. I know it's possible but I can't seem to figure out how from the docs, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at simplest munin plugins that count something per second - eg [forks](http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/branches/1.4-stable/plugins/node.d.linux/forks.in). 
you probably would like to use the data type DERIVE or COUNTER [check definitions [here](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrdtutorial.en.html)] and multiply the value returned by 60 to change from events/sec into events/minute.